# C# Saving an arraylist to a file?

Tags: c#, file, arraylist

I have a simple program where I would like to save an arraylist to a file, so that when the program is restarted, it loads from the file to the arraylist in memory.

Is this possible in C#? Or do I need to itterate over the arraylist countaining my custom classes and in someway print them out?

Any tips on a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to look into Serialization.  [Here's](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0220__Data-Structure/SerializeanArrayListobjecttoabinaryfile.htm) a link to get you going.

Comment: Looking into it. Seems to be what I need to implement at first look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes,instead of ArrayList ,use List<T> and store the data in XML file .When the program starts up read that XML file.

Comment: Sounds good, but I can't change that now since I have been using that arraylist everywhere in the program. Would rather find an alternative instead if it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the  DeSerializeObject and SerializeObject methods  in this post

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/10/04/xmlserializer-and-invalid-xml.aspx